# Bind a PictureBox to DataColum in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datatable, picturebox

I have a data repeater that contains a PictureBox and the picture needs to be fetched from a webserver. I already have a function that downloads the image, but the binding does not seem to be working. I am quite new to using windows forms and I am not too sure what I am doing wrong.

I have tried using a gridview, and I can confirm that that does show the images.

```
Public Function DlImg(ByVal _URL As String) As Byte()
    Dim _tmpImage As Image = Nothing
    Dim BytesOut As Byte()
    Try
        Dim _HttpWebRequest As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(_URL), System.Net.HttpWebRequest)
        _HttpWebRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = True
        Dim _WebResponse As System.Net.WebResponse = _HttpWebRequest.GetResponse():
        Dim _WebStream As System.IO.Stream = _WebResponse.GetResponseStream()
        _tmpImage = Image.FromStream(_WebStream)
        _WebResponse.Close()
        Using picture As Image = _tmpImage
            Using stream As New IO.MemoryStream
                picture.Save(stream, Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
                BytesOut = stream.GetBuffer()
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch _Exception As Exception
        Return Nothing
    End Try

    Return BytesOut
End Function

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ListData.Columns.Add("Image", Type.GetType("System.Byte[]"))
    For Each row As DataRow In ListData.Rows
        row("Image") = DlImg("http://rental.joshblease.co.uk/propertyimages/p184js94kv1qco1e1e1jt71ouv11lm6.jpg")
    Next row
    ImgListItem.DataBindings.Add("Image", ListData, "Image", True)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ListData
    DataRepeater1.DataSource = ListData
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try **without** data binding to see if your process is working? Right now you are trying to handle too many things at the same time, and we don't even know if the rest is handled properly.

Comment: @Neolisk I knwo that the _tmpImage returns an image and that the byte data is correct due to the images showing in a gridview, but I am not sure what you want me to do?

Comment: If the image is showing fine in a grid view, what's the problem then?